# BSOD Assistance

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Computer has been crashing a lot recently, various BSODs involved. Trying to pinpoint the problem (via Driver Validation) has only led to more crashing. Just installed and tried to use the debug program recommended on another post I was reading, and it's telling me I don't have permission to access the dump file. Anyone know how to work around this, so I can post my dump info and hopefully lead to some sort of solution?

Thanks
R

Comment: What is the error? What debug program? What is telling you you don't have permission to access what dump file, and how is it telling you?

Comment: copy the dmp files to the desktop, zip them and upload the ZIP (onedrive, dropbox and post a link here)

Comment: Use [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)

Comment: Uploaded files to dropbox. Here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6hzl8r1bm8vfjin/AAAnPIjcu0kUpTcmB5Hhyzcda      also I am trying to use the windows SDK command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You have hardware issue. 1 dump shows that the L1 cache of your CPU has an issue:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: fffffa800b04c028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000b6002000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000035000175, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_AuthenticAMD

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  NS2.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17029 (debuggers(dbg).140219-1702) amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
hal!HalBugCheckSystem
nt!WheaReportHwError
hal!HalpMcaReportError
hal!HalpMceHandler
hal!HalHandleMcheck
nt!KxMcheckAbort
nt!KiMcheckAbort
0x0



IMAGE_NAME:  AuthenticAMD

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_CACHE

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_CACHE

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x124_authenticamd_processor_cache


2: kd> !errrec fffffa800b04c028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa800b04c028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01cf8823d8a14be4
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 6/15/2014 2:57:27 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800b04c0a8
Section       @ fffffa800b04c180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 1
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000100fa0
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000002

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800b04c0f0
Section       @ fffffa800b04c240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000002
CPU Id        : a0 0f 10 00 00 08 06 02 - 09 20 80 00 ff fb 8b 17
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ fffffa800b04c240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800b04c138
Section       @ fffffa800b04c2c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : DCACHEL1_EVICT_ERR
```

The second dump shows a memory corruption:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffa801c355010, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80002b8db07, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


WRITE_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80002d070e0
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80002d07198
 fffffa801c355010 Nonpaged pool

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!MiReleaseConfirmedPageFileSpace+87
fffff800`02b8db07 480fb328        btr     qword ptr [rax],rbp

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  Setup.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
nt!MiReleaseConfirmedPageFileSpace
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!NtFreeVirtualMemory
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_nt!MiReleaseConfirmedPageFileSpace+87

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xa_nt!mireleaseconfirmedpagefilespace+87
```

The 3rd dump shows NTFS issues:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM (24)
    If you see NtfsExceptionFilter on the stack then the 2nd and 3rd
    parameters are the exception record and context record. Do a .cxr
    on the 3rd parameter and then kb to obtain a more informative stack
    trace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000000c08a2
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x24

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
Ntfs!NtfsPagingFileIo
Ntfs! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
fltmgr!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted
fltmgr!FltpDispatch
nt!IoPageRead
nt!MiIssueHardFault
nt!MmAccessFault
nt!KiPageFault
0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  Ntfs.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x24_ntfs!ntfspagingfileio+155

start             end                 module name
fffff880`01222000 fffff880`013c5000   Ntfs       (pdb symbols)          d:\sym\dl\nt\ntfs.pdb\A3FA3C11632A4FC09223AB611D6EFF7F2\ntfs.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: Ntfs.sys
    Mapped memory image file: d:\sym\dl\Nt\Ntfs.sys\4A5BC14F1a3000\Ntfs.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Ntfs.sys
    Image name: Ntfs.sys
    Timestamp:        Tue Jul 14 01:20:47 2009
```

the 4th dump also shows RAM issues:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041790, A page table page has been corrupted. On a 64 bit OS, parameter 2
    contains the address of the PFN for the corrupted page table page.
    On a 32 bit OS, parameter 2 contains a pointer to the number of used
    PTEs, and parameter 3 contains the number of used PTEs.
Arg2: fffffa80062789a0
Arg3: 000000000000ffff
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41790

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  steamerrorrepo

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!MiRemoveMappedView
nt!MiUnmapViewOfSection
nt!NtUnmapViewOfSection
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
0x0
```

So you should run [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) to check the RAM, if this is fine, run `chkdsk /f` to fix NTFS file system issues.

Comment: Thanks ever so for the info. These were all my suspicions confirmed. I have 12gb of RAM, so if I'm correct I'll have to remove some and do multiple tests? Also, is there some way around the processor corruption, besides replacing?

Comment: it is recommend to test each RAM module alone. The CPU issue can be also caused by bad RAM. So check the RAM first.

Comment: checked all RAM, found and removed one bad stick. re-tested with remaining 3 sticks, everything works fine. I'll run the chkdsk too just in case. Hoping the CPU is not damaged! Thanks again! :)

Comment: ok, looks like this bad RAM module caused it

Comment: did chkdsk find anything? If not the bad RAM was the fault of all issues. If my reply answers it, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: chkdsk didn't find anything, and I was almost convinced that removing the RAM handled the issue, until I got another non-descript BSOD today. Could you look at the .dmp file? https://www.dropbox.com/s/dj80vmp3vmm1pyl/062114-49514-01.dmp

Comment: this time you got a L1 Cache Read error: DCACHEL1_DRD_ERR. Maybe the AMD CPu is really damaged.

Comment: last time I took it off for cleaning, noticed a bent (slightly bent) pin that I VERY carefully bent back (we're talking like 1/64" maybe). I figured it would come to this, so let me ask you one last question:

Comment: Is it worth replacing the current phenom II X6 @ 3.2ghz, or should I look at upgrading the mobo to one with an AM3+ socket (vs the standard AM3 I have now), and getting a beefier one for around the same price (for both a motherboard and a chip vs just the chip)?

Comment: All AM3 mobos and CPUs are outdated. Better buy an Intel 9x Board + Haswell refresh CPU like the Xeon E3-1231 v3 which is an i7 without included graphics for around 200€. This CPU blows your old AMD away.